# PyCharm Bootstrap autocomplete issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am having an issue getting PyCharm to auto complete Bootstrap. For example I am unable to get `col-sm-12 col-md-7` to autoshow/complete. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to fix this?

Sure -- download Bootstrap's `.css` files locally -- place them in your project.

PyCharm (and other JetBrains IDE) cannot use remote URLs for code completion -- you have to have local versions of them in the project (even if you do not actually use them).